# GIMP How to slice a shape properly?

Tags: gimp, path

[image]

I used the path tool to select these segments but now there is a one pixel wide alpha line between them, what's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Where is this gap - at the lower edge of the white area?

Comment: As for the problem itself, my guess would be that your path was not exactly aligned with the pixel grid, but to turn that into the answer it would be helpful to have the whole XCF file with that path for verification.

Answer (score 1):

Path tool does feather the selection slightly.

The way I normally would do that selection is with the ellipse and lasso "Free Select" tools. The lasso tool can be used as a point to point tool as well as a click and drag tool.

To select the "pie" from your image, I'd single click a corner, then single click the opposite corner, and repeat until closing the selection polygon.

(Holding Ctrl between points snaps to 15 degree angles)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions